# How many publications is seen as a good number for a Ph.D. thesis defender in CS field?

Tags: publications, phd, computer-science, europe, defense

I know that the question may sound a bit context related (country, university, topic of the Ph.D.) but in general nowadays, how many publications (conference + journal) are Ph.D. students required to have to safely present at their Ph.D. thesis defence ?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be as low as zero, actually. But it depends on place and the form of the thesis. Where are you asking about?

Comment: norway and germany

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspect, it depends on context. Most of all, it depends on the subfield. In machine learning, for example, the rate of publication is much greater than in other fields, e.g. multiple papers per year; where in some areas, such as theory and systems, it can be that one spends 3 years working on a single major paper or result.

Also: most fundamentally, graduation is not dependent on meeting a certain publication threshold; rather, it is up to **whether your advisor wants you to graduate and whether you have met all the requirements of your program.**

With these caveats out of the way, **a general rule of thumb** is at least 3 publications for which the student has made a primary contribution to, and which are in the same or a similar topic or problem space.

Notes on this:

- "Primary contribution" usually means first author or shared-first author; the question is whether that paper can be included in the student's thesis. If the student is not first author, then  they should at least be closely involved enough that they can take responsibility for the paper content.
- "Similar topic or problem space" is quite subject to interpretation. It may be, for example, that two unrelated papers can be compiled together in the same thesis if the author can find a way to tell a story of how they are related. I have even seen theses that simply have two parts, and the introduction will say "Part 1 is about problem A, part 2 is about problem B."
- It is common for PhD students who publish less than their peers to graduate anyway, if they and their advisor want them to. For example, if a PhD student reaches their 5th or 6th year and they only have 1-2 papers, but they have already found a job, they will likely be able to graduate with their advisor's endorsement.
- Finally, you should look to a particular institution and/or a particular advisor for specific requirements, either formal or informal. It is likely that more competitive universities will have a higher publication standard compared to lower-tier universities. And some advisors consider the exact publication count to be important, while others do not.